# Capistrano: linked file composer.lock does not exist on IP

Tags: ruby, deployment, capistrano

I don't know what I did wrong, but why the `composer.lock` file doesn't exist? I added it to the `linked_files`. Here's my console output:

```
 DEBUG [8df0d002] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /var/www/html/my_site/shared /var/www/html/my_site/shared/sites/default
  INFO [8df0d002] Finished in 0.614 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [b06431bc] Running [ -f /var/www/html/my_site/shared/composer.lock ] as deploy@xxx.xx.xxx.xx
 DEBUG [b06431bc] Command: [ -f /var/www/html/my_site/shared/composer.lock ]
 DEBUG [b06431bc] Finished in 0.614 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 ERROR linked file /var/www/html/my_site/shared/composer.lock does not exist on xxx.xx.xxx.xx
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Here's my Capfile:

```
require "capistrano/setup"
require "capistrano/deploy"
require "capistrano/composer"
require 'capistrano/file-permissions'

# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock '3.5.0'
set :application, 'my_site'
set :repo_url, 'sample@xxx.xx.xxx.xx:hello/my_site.git'

#Composer installation Flag set
set :composer_install_flags, '--no-interaction --optimize-autoloader'
#Composer path in the Webserver, so check with DSU for this path
SSHKit.config.command_map[:composer] = "/usr/bin/composer"

# Default branch is :master
# ask :branch, `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp

# Path where application code will be deployed in Webservers
set :deploy_to, '/var/www/html/my_site/'
#Setting Files/Folders as linked
set :linked_files, ["composer.lock", "sites/default/settings.php", ".htaccess"]
set :linked_dirs, ["core", "vendor", "sites/default/files"]

# Setting Files/Folders permission
set :file_permissions_paths, ["sites/default/files", "private-files"]
set :file_permissions_users, ["deploy"]
set :file_permissions_groups, ["apache"]
set :file_permissions_chmod_mode, "0775"

# Default value for :scm is :git
set :scm, :git

# Default value for :format is :pretty
set :format, :pretty

# Default value for :log_level is :debug
set :log_level, :debug

# Default value for keep_releases is 5
set :keep_releases, 4

namespace :deploy do

    after :restart, :clear_cache do
        on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
            # Here we can do anything such as:
            # within release_path do
            #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
        end
    end

    task :composer do
        on roles(:app) do
            invoke 'composer:install'
        end
    end

    desc 'Delete failed release'
        task :rm_failed do
            on roles(:all) do
                execute(:rm, "-rf #{release_path}")
        end
    end

end

# Composer installation
after 'deploy:updated', 'deploy:composer'

#Files/Folders permission set
after "deploy:updated", "deploy:set_permissions:chown"
after "deploy:updated", "deploy:set_permissions:chgrp"
after "deploy:updated", "deploy:set_permissions:chmod"

#If failure in latest release then latest release folder will be deleted automatically
after "deploy:failed", "deploy:rm_failed"
```

Can you provide any solution for this?

Also what does `invoke 'composer:install'` do?

FYI, I don't have SSH access to the server so I can't check if the composer.lock file is there, also I don't know anything about capistrano and ruby.

Comment: Within capistrano `invoke 'composer:install'` run the step that is named `'composer:install'` which comes with this [plugin](https://github.com/capistrano/composer). The plugin needs some configuration and it seems like some of the configs aren't okay. If you do not have access to the server, who wrote the capistrano script? Where did you get the configs - especially the paths - from? What version of the composer plugin to you use (find in Gemfile.lock)?

Comment: Thanks @spickermann, followup question,, what does ```deploy:composer``` do?

Comment: Just have a look at its source code: https://github.com/capistrano/composer/blob/master/lib/capistrano/tasks/composer.rake

Comment: I don't understand, where do I look?

Comment: I does what you defined in your `Capfile` (see: `task :composer do`)  it runs `invoke 'composer:install'` what is a task defined in the file above.